# AJAX-подгрузка контента на скроллинге срабатывает нормально только один раз

Tags: jquery, ajax

Я хочу сделать страницу с "бесконечным скроллингом". Что-бы в конце страницы подгружался контент следующей страницы итд.

Функция подгрузки привязана к скроллингу. Когда мы доходим до определнной триггерной точки, подгружается контент.

Первая подгрузка срабатывает нормально. Последующие подгрузки остальных страниц срабатывают на каждое скроллинг-событие. То есть весь последующий контент подгружается мгновенно пока я скроллю. Как это исправить? Я уже всю голову сломал.

Вот страница над которой я работаю:
http://viimiracula.ru/russian/aboutnew/about.htm

Вот код самого скрипта:

```
//VARS

var currentcontentid = parseInt($("div.content").attr('id').replace(/content/, '')),
    nextcontentid = parseInt(currentcontentid) + 1,
    previouscontentid = parseInt(currentcontentid) - 1,
    currentContent = $('#content' + currentcontentid),
    nextContent = $('#content' + nextcontentid),      
    $window = $(window),
    fired = 0;
var pages = ['about.htm','architectural-concrete.htm','artists.htm','calculate-production.htm','classifier1.htm','classifier2.htm','decorative-concrete.htm','learnsculpture.htm','manufacturing-technology.htm','service.htm','technical-characteristics.htm','tips-to-new-customers1.htm','tips-to-new-customers2.htm'];
var nextpageurl = pages[nextcontentid];
var contentOffset = $('#content' + currentcontentid).offset().top;       
var contentHeight = $('#content' + currentcontentid).height();
var windowHeight = $window.height();
var triggerHeight = contentOffset + contentHeight - windowHeight;
var marginOldContent = contentOffset + contentHeight;

var fired = 0;

//Loaded content margin

$('.content').css('height', windowHeight);       
$('head').append('<style>#content' + nextcontentid + '{margin-top:' + windowHeight + 'px;}</style>');

//Load on scroll function

$(window).on('scroll',function() {

    var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
    var triggerHeight = contentOffset + contentHeight - windowHeight;

    $('.scroll3').html("Scrolling position:" + scroll);
    $('.scroll2').html("Trigger position:" + triggerHeight);


    if (scroll >= triggerHeight){
        var urlPath =  "/russian/aboutnew/" + nextpageurl;
        $("body").append('<div class="content" id="content' + nextcontentid + '"></div>');
        $("#content" + nextcontentid).load("/russian/aboutnew/" + nextpageurl + " .content");

        $('#content' + currentcontentid).css('margin-top', - marginOldContent);
        $('#content' + currentcontentid).css('position', 'fixed');


        //Previous content fade out

        var header = $('#content' + currentcontentid);
        var range = 200;

        $(window).on('scroll', function () {                  
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
                height = header.outerHeight(),
                offset = height / 2,
                calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;
            header.css({ 'opacity': calc });

          if (calc > '1') {
            header.css({ 'opacity': 1 });
          } else if ( calc < '0' ) {
            header.css({ 'opacity': 0 });
          }

        }); 

        //Changing URL              

        window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", urlPath);

        //Changing Title

        $.ajax({
            url: urlPath,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {
            $('.scroll').text(html);
            var title = $('.scroll').text($(html).filter('title').text());                    
            document.title = $('.scroll').html();
            }       
        });  


        currentcontentid = currentcontentid + 1;
        nextcontentid = nextcontentid + 1;
        nextpageurl = pages[nextcontentid];
        contentOffset = $('#content' + currentcontentid).offset().top;
        contentHeight = $('#content' + currentcontentid).outerHeight( true );
        windowHeight = $window.height();


        $('.scroll3').html(scroll);
        $('.scroll2').html(triggerHeight);

    }else{

    };

/*if ($window.scrollTop() >= menudistance - 70) {
    $('.submenupage2').css('position','fixed');
    $('.submenupage2').css('top','70px');
}else{
    $('.submenupage2').css('position','static');
    $('.submenupage2').css('top','70px');
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        $('.submenupage4').css('position','static');
    }       
});*/     
});
});
```

Comment: Зачем вам `$(window).on('scroll')` внутри другого  `$(window).on('scroll')` ?

Comment: Хороший вопрос) Но к самому механизму подгрузки контента обсуждаемому в вопросе он не имеет отношения. Но все равно спасибо подправлю)